# How to navigate to a different page for a simple django application in Shopify App iFrame

Tags: django, shopify, shopify-app

Hello I am trying to create a Shopify Django application. I have created a page which list sets of Magic: the Gathering. I want to be able to click a set to be taken to a page that displays more details of that set.

The set page is has the following URL:

- [https://admin.shopify.com/store/{store](https://admin.shopify.com/store/%7Bstore) name}/apps/{app name}/magic/sets/

This page loads as expected and I am able to use the functionality on this page such as searching for a set.

However when I click on a set it doesn't navigate to set details page. The html code for this in `<a class="" href="{{ set_code }}/">...</a>` which should add the set code to the end of the URL. If I type the URL manually it works as expected and the set details page loads.

I am using ngrok to create the tunnel between Shopify and my dev environment so I can view the application in the Shopify Admin UI, but I don't know why is not navigating properly when using the link in the iframe.

Is there a specific way navigation should be done in the iframe

Comment: Local url (not starting with `/`) will start from the host. There is no other way then recreating the full local url (starting from `/store`).

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the issue. I need to has the `shop` query to the url as shown below:

```html
<a class="" href="{{ set_code }}/?shop={{ shop_origin }}">...</a>
```